# Mapping class group of a torus

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, mapping-class-group

Seems like i have some false understanding that need to be fixed. I have check varies sources saying that the mapping class group of a torus is isomorphic to $GL(2,\mathbb Z)$, however my false intuition tells me it should be $SL(2,\mathbb Z)$. Dehn-Lickorish theorem tells us any orientation preserving homeomorphism of a genus $g$ surface can be generated by a product of Dehn twists along 3g-1 curves, in the case of the torus, the curves are the meridian and the preferred longitude. If we consider a homeomorphisms generated by Dehn twists as induced map of linear transformation in the covering space, then MCG($T^2$) should be isomorphic to the group genenrated by $\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 1
\end{array} \right]$, $\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{array} \right]$, where this two matrix corresponds to Dehn twist along meridian and longitude if we compose the matrix with the projection map. But then these two matrices are the generators of $SL(2,\mathbb Z)$, so I thought MCG($T^2$) should be isomorphic to $SL(2,\mathbb Z)$. Could you help me have a look where my understanding went wrong?

Comment: It depends on the definition of the MCG. Some authors only consider isotopy classes of orientation-preserving diffeomorphisms, while other authors do not make this assumption.